# Batch File Variable to copy specific files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to copy specific files from `C:` to "`X:` for example". The files are named with the same format.

```
A1234_ZZabc123_DT1_F1.tst 
A4567_ZZdef4567_DT2_F2.tst 
A8901_ZZghi1289_DT1.tst 
A2345_ZZjfkbu12_to_modify.tst 
A6789_ZZlmny568_F1_to_modify.tst 
A1234_ZZabc478_DT1.txt
```

I want to copy only the `.tst` files, and with the same format as the first 3 `Axxxx_ZZyyyxxx_DTx_Fx.tst` where `x`=number and `y`=letter.

After ZZ, it might be 4 letters and 3 numbers, or 5 letters and 4 numbers, like a "namecode".
Example: `ZZkusha122` or `ZZkus1551`.
I need to copy the folders along with the files too.

I'm new to coding and really need some help.

I need to find and copy all those files along 10k+ files together

Comment: Have you tried ```copy "C:\A????_ZZ???_DT?_F?.tst" Z:\```

Comment: I have reverted your question back to its previous state. Please do not change it again, I did it for a reason, you may not have liked it, but you are new here, and my reason was better for this site and its readership.

Comment: Hello @Compo thanks for answering. I tried to copy from a folder to another folder at the local disc but somehow it dosnt copy at all. This is my line : 'copy "C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi\A????_ZZ???_DT?_F?.tst" "C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\Aoi Destination"' . In the folder "aoi" there are more folders witch seperate all the files i want to copy, and i want to copy the folders as well. Means i need to keep their place but copy only what i need.

Comment: Forgot to mention, after ZZ is not specifically 3 letters, it might be 4 letters and 3 numbers, or 5 letters and 4 numbers, like a "namecode". Example: ZZkusha122 or ZZkus100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim that the first 3 of your example filenames fit the pattern you describe. I believe that only two do.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\A*.tst"^|findstr /X /I /R "A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ[a-z][a-z][a-z]_DT[0-9]_F[0-9].tst" '
 ) DO ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%%e" X:
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Simply execute a `dir` command that reports only filenames matching the `*.tst` mask. Filter this list with `findstr` which `/X` exactly matches the regular expression provided. `findstr` only has a limited implementation of regular expressions. The `/I` forces a case-insensitive match. If you want case-sensitive, remove the `/I` and change each `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` (leave as-is if you want lower-case only in these positions.)

See `findstr /?` from the prompt for more documentation, or search for examples on SO.

---- revision to cater for multiple filemasks and subdirectories ---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "maskfile=%sourcedir%\q74442552.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b/s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.tst"^|findstr /E /I /R /g:"%maskfile%" '
 ) DO ECHO COPY "%%e" X:
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Changes:

1. Establish a file, name irrelevant, as `maskfile`
2. The `dir` command requires the `/s` switch to scan subdirectories
3. The filemask for the `dir` command loses the initial `A`
4. The `findstr` command replaces the `/X` switch with `/E`
5. The `findstr` command loses the regex expression. These are transferred to a file and the file is nominated by the `/g:` switch.
6. The `copy` command loses the source-directory as the directory will be included in `%%e`

The file "q74442552.txt" contains lines that are of the form

```
A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ[a-z][a-z][a-z]_DT[0-9]_F[0-9].tst
A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ[a-z][a-z][a-z]_to.*.tst
```

This time, `%%e` acquires the full pathname of the files found. Since the filemask ends `.tst`, the only filenames to pass the `dir` filter will be those that end `.tst`.

The `/e` switch tells `findstr` to match string that **E**nd with the regex strings in the file specified as `/g:`.

The strings in the file must comply with Microsoft's partial `regex` implementation, one to a line.

In summary, `findstr` uses as `regex`

- Any character,literally
- [set] any character of a set of characters
- [^set] any character not in a set of characters
- . any character
- .* any number of any character
- prefix any of the special characters with`\` to use it literally
- a set may include a range by using `low-high`

So - you then need to brew-your own using the examples I've supplied. The second line matches `Axxxx_ZZyyy_to{anything}.tst` for instance.

--- Minor revision to deal with maintaining destination-tree -----
(see notes to final revision for why this doesn't *quite* work)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "maskfile=%sourcedir%\q74442552.txt"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b/s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.tst"^|findstr /E /I /R /g:"%maskfile%" '
 ) DO ECHO "%%~nxe"&XCOPY /Y /D /S "%sourcedir%\%%~nxe" "%destdir%\">nul
)
   
GOTO :EOF
```

This version adds the destination root directory as `destdir`.

The `dir ... findstr...` works as before to list the filenames to copy.

The prior version used `echo copy` to report the proposed copy operation, but the destination was always the same directory.

The replacement `XCOPY` line maintains the directory structure at the destination.

Note : the `XCOPY` is "live". The files will be copied to the destination if run as-is. **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

To "defuse" the `XCOPY`, add the `/L` switch and remove the `>nul`. This will cause `XCOPY` to report the source name that would be copied instead of `copying` it. (The `>nul` suppresses the report)

The `/D` only copies source files that eitherr do not exist in the destination of have a later datestamp in the source.

The action is to `xcopy` each file**name** found (`%%~nxe`) from the source directory tree to the destination. Therefore, any file `xyz.tst` found anywhere in the source tree will be `xcopy`d to the destination tree. The `/D` means that once `xyz.tst` is encountered on the source tree, it will be skipped should it be encountered again.

--- Final (I hope) revision ---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=U:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi"
SET "maskfile=%sourcedir%\q74442552.txt"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b/s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.tst"^|findstr /E /I /R /g:"%maskfile%" '
 ) DO (
  rem drive and path to 'dirname' - has terminal "\"
  SET "dirname=%%~dpe"
  rem remove the sourcedir from dirname
  FOR %%y IN ("%sourcedir%") DO CALL SET "dirname=%%dirname:%%~y=%%"
  rem copy or xcopy the file to the destination. 
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%y IN ('set dirname') DO XCOPY /Y "%%e" "%destdir%%%y">nul
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note to self: Only if the filemask provided to `XCOPY` is ambiguous (ie. contains `?` or `*`) will XCOPY obey the `/s` switch unless the target file exists in the starting source directory.

hence

```
xcopy /s sourcedir\myfile destdir
```

will copy `myfile` from the entire tree **ONLY** if `sourcedir\myfile` exists.

```
xcopy /s sourcedir\myf?le destdir
```

will copy `myfile` from the entire tree regardless. **Unfortunately** it will also copy `myfale` and `myfule` as well.

Hence, the new approach.

First, perform a `dir /b /s` to get all of the filenames and filter as before. This is being assigned to `%%e`.

Take the drive and path only of the file and assign to `dirname`.

The next step is a little complex. First, set the value of `%%y` to the name of the source directory. Next, use a parser trick to remove that name from `dirname`. The mechanics are: Parse the `%%dirname:%%~y=%%` (because the `call` causes the `set` to be executed in a sub-shell) whuch does the normal left-to-right evaluation. `%%` is an escaped-%, so is replaced by `%`; `%%y` is an active metavariable so is replaced by (the name of the source directory) and the `~` causes the quotes to be stripped from that name. The resultant command executed is thus `SET "dirname=%dirname:nameofsourcedirectory=%"`

So now we can construct a `copy`-class instruction. `dirname` now contains the *relative* directory for the destination, which we can extract from the environment by parsing a `set` listing (Could also be done with `delayed expansion`) where `%%y` gets set to the relative directory and has both a leading and trailing backslash, so the destination directory is simply `"%destdir%%%y"`. `XCOPY` then knows to create that directory if necessary (`%%y` has a trailing backslash) and we know the source filename is in `%%e`.

You could also use a `copy` to do the same thing, but you'd need to create the destination directory first. Another advantage of `XCOPY` is that you can also specify the `/d` switch to not copy files that have an earlier date over files that have a later date.

Comment: Hello @Magoo, thanks for helping. Acctually the first 3 formats needs to be copied.
Those with _Fx and those without _Fx, (x for number).
Also, after ZZ is not specifically 3 letters, it might be 4 letters and 3 numbers,
or 5 letters and 4 numbers, like a "namecode".
Example: ZZkusha122 or ZZkus100
I need to keep the folders as they are too.

Comment: Please consider that im pretty new at this and i need additional info so i don't mess up. :D

Comment: Hey @Magoo , I tried your code but still can't make it work for my case

Comment: You have substantially changed the requirements.  I would claim that the code works according to your original specification; one directory and filenames fitting the `Axxxx_ZZyyy_DTx_Fx.tst` pattern. A solution can only be devised when there is a solid specification. "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. To solve a problem we need to know what the code does that it shouldn't do and doesn't do what it should. So - does the solution I posted behave correctly for files matching `Axxxx_ZZyyy_DTx_Fx.tst` in the target directory?

Comment: I created a file with the format "Axxxx_ZZyyy_DTx_Fx.tst" to test it but  still doesn't work.
At `SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"` I changed the `u:\your files` with my folder location.
Then i removed the `/I` from findstr to include `[a-zA-Z]`.
Finaly removed `ECHO` at `DO COPY` and added the location i want to paste the files.

Comment: This is my code so far:
`@echo off
setlocal

set "sourcedir=C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi"

for /f "delims=" %%e IN (
' dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\A*.tst"^|findstr /x /r "A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]_DT[0-9]_F[0-9].tst" '
 ) do copy "%sourcedir%\%%e" "C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\Aoi_Destination"
)
goto :eof`

Comment: It is working now for the files matching `Axxxx_ZZyyy_DTx_Fx.tst` . i added `" "` to destination.

Comment: Hello @magoo , thanks alot for the solution, is working perfectly for the files i need to copy,
I writed this on the "q74442552.txt" file  `A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ.*_DT[0-9]_F[0-9].tst`
`A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ.*_DT[0-9].tst`
`A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_ZZ.*_DT[0-9]_F[0-9] .tst` and is recognising all my files.

All is left to do now is to copy the folders along the files. You really helped me here so thanks alot.

Comment: Copying folders along files is harder than it looks (for me). Tried Xcopy and Robocopy but can't make it to work.
I can copy the folders and files but they are all "listed" to the destination, files aren't pasted into their folder.
Here is what i wrided so far: 
`DO XCOPY "%%e" "C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\Aoi_Destination" /S /E`

Comment: Somehow, now it doesn't copy the `.tst` files at all. 
And it doesn't copy the tree destination. 
The only thing that is copied, is a `.tst` file that is 'directly' on the source directory. 
No subdirectories or files on them are copied at all. 
I tried with some other commands of XCOPY but still can't make it work.

Comment: I've re-applied the code to the last revision, just in case there was a posting error. The code works quite happily for me. You are aware that this version should create a subtree containing all of the files, are you not? I've added `ECHO "%%~nxe"&` before the `xcopy` to display the filenames that are detected for debugging purposes. Note that removing the `>nul` from the end of the `xcopy` statement should allow `xcopy`'s report to be displayed. This may give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: So @Magoo this is what the report shows: " [ ZZ........tst ]. File not found - [ ZZ..........tst ] ". 
The code copy all `.tst` files on `C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi` but doesn't copy the folders 
or the files on `C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi\folder1`, `C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi\folder1_1` 
`C:\Users\tocil\Desktop\aoi\folder2` and so on.

Comment: I've found the root of the problem. Working on it...

Comment: Now it just got more and more complicated (for me). I'll try to process and understand the code so I learn to deal with similar problems myself. The code works super well. It does exactly what I need. I don't know how to thank you enough though. I just hope it was a challenge for you and you learned something too. Thanks alot @Magoo ! :)